# Getting an error with my for loop involving numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm making a game and I'm getting the error: "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices."

In the following block of code, play_game is a function that returns a string, and roll_dice is a random array. Basically, I'm trying to get all the strings into an array, so into total_games. However, I can't do this because of this error, which I'm not sure exactly what it means. If someone could clarify what the error means or how I can fix this code it'd be greatly appreciated.

```py
def game_session(num_games=50):
    total_games = np.zeros(num_games)
    for i in total_games:
        total_games[i] = play_game(roll_dice())
    return total_games
```

Answer (score 1):

`.zeros` creates an array of floating point zeros (`0.0`).

When you do `for i in total_games`, `i` will always be `0.0` and obviously `total_games[0.0]` can't be done for the reason your error message suggets.

I belive what you want is `for i in range(len(total_games))` which will iterate through the indicies of `total_games`, ie 0, 1, 2, 3, ....

Comment: Doing that fixes it, but now I get an error: could not convert string to float. This is because play_game() returns a string

Comment: In that case, the answer @Szymon Maszke provided may be more what you need.

Comment: Ok yea. Only problem with that one is it has to be the size of the parameter num_games and I can't iterate through an empty list.

Comment: @JoeyJordan is that what you are after?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke yea sorry I should've clarified. I need it to be the size of num_games

Answer (score 1):

You cannot input string into `np.array` of type `np.float64`, as this data structure contains only one type (by default `np.float64` as in this example).

What you are after is a normal Python's `list`, try this code:

```
def game_session(num_games=50):
    total_games = []
    for _ in range(num_games):
        total_games.append(play_game(roll_dice()))
    return total_games
```

[@Loocid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565265/getting-an-error-with-my-for-loop-involving-numpy-arrays/55565289#55565289)'s answer is also right, there are multiple problems with your code.

Actually you can (and probably should) do it more pythonic like this:

```
def game_session(num_games=50):
    return [play_game(roll_dice()) for _ in range(num_games)]
```